# Pyqt5 accessing violation of variable storing folder_path taken from getExistingDirectory function into another function

Tags: python, variables, pyqt

I created a simple GUi using pyqt5 where I am taking the input directory path using the get existing directory function and I am storing it in a variable but I am unable to access the variable or the folder path in another function.
In the Gui I take two paths one is input folder path and the other is output folder path and I created a 3rd button which when clicked will go into a function and then i am trying to use the both paths taken and send them as input arguments to another py file and run it using subprocess but I am unable to get the  folder paths in my third function and I want to pass both paths as input arguments. What will be the best way to do it.
here is the code

```
class App(QWidget):
          def __init__(self):
                    super().__init__()
                    self.setWindowTitle('Avizo')
                    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('logo.png'))
                    self.resize(600,239)

                    self.button1 = QPushButton('Input folder')
                    self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 681, 28))
                    self.button1.clicked.connect(self.get_input_dir)
                    

                    self.button2 = QPushButton('Select Outputfolder')
                    self.button2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 681, 28))
                    self.button2.clicked.connect(self.get_Output_dir)
                    
                    self.button4 = QPushButton('calculate')
                    self.button4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 180, 161, 28))
                    self.button4.clicked.connect(self.calculate)
                    
                    layout = QVBoxLayout()
                    layout.addWidget(self.button1)
                    layout.addWidget(self.button2)
                    layout.addWidget(self.button3)
                    self.setLayout(layout)
                    self.initUI()
        def initUI(self):
                    self.show()

        def get_input_dir(self):
                    input_path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select  Output Folder')
                    print(input_path)
                    #print(image_paths)
                    return input_path

        def get_Output_dir(self):
                    output_path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select  Output Folder')
                    #print(output_path)
        def cropmodule(self):
                   x=get_input_dir()
                   print(x)
                   subprocess.Popen(['python', 'file.py'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    Demo = App()
    

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: 10-spaces indentation is a bit too much, can you please edit your code and reduce it to the standard 4?

Comment: (1) Return the path from the methods. (2) Call the methods: e.g. `x = self.get_input_dir()`.

Comment: I solved that issue but I am unable to pass the input path i obtained from here to my next file and then run it using subprocess